# Total no of row returned for exp:channel:entries?

Tags: ee2, query, count

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_1"}
//how do i find the total no of entries retuned without exp:query?
{/exp/channel:entries}
```

I want to find the count first and then loop?Any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the total number of entries returned from your exp:channel:entries tag use the variable {total_results}.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_1"}
{total_results}
{/exp/channel:entries}
```

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#total-results

But I'm not sure I understand why you "want to find the count first and then loop?"

The exp:channel:entries tag *is* a loop. It will loop through the code within the tag for every entry returned by it. That's what it is for.

Comment: i want to count the no of entries returned by tag and if its less than 1 ,then i want to i want to take some action..

Comment: If if was less than 1 (i.e. no results) the loop itself would come back empty.  So you could use the if no_results conditional to take that action without needing the total_results conditional.

Comment: As Jean says, use the {no_results} tag pair. I highly recommend reading everything on that page I linked to.